# Query no Mongo não está funcionando quando tenho uma propriedade composta (uma dentro da outra)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando realizar uma query no banco do mongo, quando tenho uma propriedade simples como por exemplo:

> `Nome: João`

Funciona sem problemas

Mas se tenho uma propriedade composta como por exemplo:

> `Tamanho: 
>     { 
>     PP: 2
>     M: 4
>     G: 10
>     }`

A consulta não retorna nenhum valor, estou tentando implantar uma consulta para retornar todos valores que sejam PP e menores que 10 por exemplo, porém, diferente do que acontece em uma consulta simples, não consigo obter sucesso

Abaixo segue o código

```js
router.get('/produtos', function (req, res) {

    _produto.paginate(
        { quantidade: { PP: { $lt: 10 } } },
        { limit: 21, page: req.query.pag, sort: { nome: 'asc' } },

        (err, res) => {
            if (!res.page) {
                res.page = 1
                res.nextPage = 2
                res.hasPrevPage = false
                res.hasNextPage = true
            }
            return res

        }).then(function (produto) {
            res.render('produtos', { produto: produto.docs, pag: produto })
        })
})
```

Abaixo segue o schema, a consulta funciona para todas propriedades simples, somente para as compostas que está com problema, provavelmente uma falha minha

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const Produto = new Schema({
    nome: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    marca: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    categoria: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantidade: {
        PP: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        P: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        M: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        G: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        GG: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _1: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _2: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _3: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _4: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _5: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _6: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _7: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _8: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _9: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _10: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _12: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _14: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        _16: {
            type: Number,
            required: false,
        }
    },
    estacao: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    descricao: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    preco: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    genero: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cor: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desconto: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    largura: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    altura: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    comprimento: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    peso: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    fotos: {
        foto1: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        foto2: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        foto3: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        foto4: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        foto5: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        }
    },
    cadastro: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})

Produto.plugin(mongoosePaginate)

mongoose.model('produto', Produto)
```

Estou utilizando o mongoose junto do mongoose-paginate

Comment: Que mal lhe pergunte, você precisa de *schema*, tudo indica que tem necessidade de relacionamentos, e duvido que precisa de escala monstro, porque preferiu usar MongoDB e não um banco de dados relacional que parece mais adequado? Provavelmente suas dificuldades sejam por estar usando a ferramenta errada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para o problema é mais simples do que pensei
Para acessar uma propriedade dentro de outra, é só passar o nome desta como string, e com isso, executar a query como deseja.

Ao invés de:

```
{ quantidade: { PP: { $lt: 10 } } }
```

Deve se usar:

```
{ 'quantidade.PP': { $lt: 10 } }
```

Sendo assim o código fica:

```js
router.get('/produtos', function (req, res) {

    _produto.paginate(
        { 'quantidade.PP': { $lt: 10 } },
        { limit: 21, page: req.query.pag, sort: { nome: 'asc' } },

        (err, res) => {
            if (!res.page) {
                res.page = 1
                res.nextPage = 2
                res.hasPrevPage = false
                res.hasNextPage = true
            }
            return res

        }).then(function (produto) {
            res.render('produtos', { produto: produto.docs, pag: produto })
        })
})
```

Espero que esta solução ajude alguem no futuro